# Problem in pressing "s" in vs code latest version

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am not able to press the key "s" in visual studio code
I can press "s" only when I press shift key, but I don't need capital "s"
please help me.

Comment: Does it work in other programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problen since I installed the `snippet-creator` extension.
You can change key-map shortcut in vscode setting, press the `manage icon` at the botom left corner of vscode and choose `key-map shortcut`, look for the `shist-s` and change it.